# Change labelText in user control outside its own .cs

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, windows-mobile-6.5

I have been googling for the last few days but without a result.

I have a Form called MainForm, i placed four user controls on it.
These user controls contain labels and buttons. Now i created a file called Language.cs
In this file i want to change the languages for all labels when a button is pressed in one of my user controls.
When i coded this in ucSettings.cs i would do it like:

```
this.label1.Text = res_man.GetString("label_text", cul);
```

But this doesnt work, beccause my Resourcemanager and my Culture info are both in another file.
So i have

- MainForm contains four user controls
- The user controls are called, ucAnimalInfo, ucAnimalInput, ucSettings and ucMenuStrip
- I have a button in ucSettings that would have to change the language
- The text should be set in the file Language.cs

As you can see i change the culture info when a language is selected in a ComboBox:

```
private void Settings_Language_Cbox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string SelectedIndex = Settings_Language_Cbox.SelectedItem.ToString();

        switch (SelectedIndex)
        {
            case "English(English)":
                ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
                LanguageSelection = 5;
                break;
            case "Nederlands(Dutch)":
                ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-NL");
                LanguageSelection = 6;
                break;
         }
```

Now i would like to do something like:

```
private void Settings_Save_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Language.Change();     
    }
```

So that it calls my Change method in Language.cs and change a the labels to the correct language. But now i am not able to acces any of the labels in Language.cs even tho they are on public, also my Language.cs file isnt able to get the Resourcemanager and CultureInfo from ucSettings.cs. So my question is, wat is the best way to handle this? I tried using a get/set method but this didn't work out at all, now i am not sure if it is because i messed this up or not.

Edit: I got close by doing it like: 
ucSettings.cs

```
private void Settings_Save_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Settings_Language_Cbox.SelectedIndex = LanguageSelection;
        BusinessClasses.Language language = new BusinessClasses.Language();
        language.setLanguage();
    }
```

Language.cs:

```
    public class Language
{
    public MainForm mainform;
    public ucAnimalInfo animalinfo;
    public ucAnimalInput animalinput;
    public ucSettings settings;


    public void setLanguage()
    {
        mainform.Animal_Info_Tab.Info_Id_Text.Text = mainform.Settings_Tab.rs.GetString("Info_Save_Btn", mainform.Settings_Tab.ci);

    }
```

it still gives a NullReferenceException so it not really working, but the closest i got so far. rs and ci are the resourcemanager and cultureinfo

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, you say user controllers but mean? user control...

As you are new to Windows Mobile/Compact Framework you should start with a simple project first and then evolute to what you want, using small steps.

A good starting for language resource localization maybe at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28234/Survival-guide-to-do-resource-localization-using-C.
Use that and then extend with a simple user control and so on.

Then also read http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16091/User-Interface-Localization-with-the-Compact-Frame about changing the languge 'on-the-fly'.

Please just supply your idea / need (I want to allow this and show that) if you need further assistance.

Comment: I will definitely read those articles Thanks, I also edited my post to try and explain it a little bit better.